# An observation on Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Let $\beta(n)$ represent the number of Goldbach prime pairs that each add up to an even integer $n$.

Observation: If $p$ is a prime, for $n \ge 152$, (ignoring $n$ = powers of $2$)

$$\beta(n) \le \beta(p*n) < p*\beta(n)$$

For powers of $2$, the above inequality is true for $n \ge 128$.

Since any number $m$ can be obtained by multiplying primes, replacing $p$ with $m$ in the above inequality would work as well.

Implication: If we start with some $n = 2p$, we know that $\beta(2p) \ge 1$. And so proving the above inequality would prove GC.

**Question**: If this inequality is indeed true, how would one go about proving it? What approaches would you take? Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Upto which number did you check the double-inequality ?

Comment: I have access to one million primes.. So whatever the even number is above the last one.

Comment: the left inequality is enough to prove GC if it holds true for all primes(integers as well).

Comment: I am curious. Why are people trying to close this question. Can someone please explain? Thanks

Comment: I wrote my question at the end of this post. Let me know if that is still unclear. If not, could you remove the hold please? Thanks

Comment: So you're asking for hints on proving Goldbach's conjecture? I guess you won't get a lot.

Comment: In general there must be some techniques for proving inequalities. I am looking for hints along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

68 can only be written in two ways as the sum of 2 primes (7 + 61, 31 + 37), however 34 can be written in 4 ways as the sum of 2 primes (17 + 17, 31 + 3, 23 + 11, 29 + 5).

Then $\beta(68) = 2$ and $\beta(34) = 4$ and $68 = 2 * 34$, with 2 being prime...

I am definitely not sure that your inequality is correct. We also have $\beta(152)=4$ and $\beta(76)=5$.

Comment: Yes, numbers below 128 being small behave funky. I missed this one. Thanks

Comment: @sku I found another example, above 128 this time...